# What's another library same as LightGallery but free (MIT license)

Tags: jquery, gallery, slide, lightgallery

LightGallery is consistent with what I desire ([LightGallery](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/index.html)). However, it is not free for web sales. Can you help me to find other free libraries that function like LightGallery (thumbs, zoom and responsive on mobile)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

An almost identical free alternaive is photoswipe (http://photoswipe.com/),
but it has less features.